# Avoid optional checking when accessing a vector

Tags: rust, option-type

How can I avoid the optional checking when accessing a `Vec`?

```
while !self.stack.is_empty() {
    let top_path;

    if let Some(top) = self.stack.last() {
        top_path = top.to_vec();
    } else {
        panic!("error (but can't happen, becouse the stack can't be empty becouse of the while loop)");
    }

    self.stack.pop();
    self.apply_grammar(top_path);
}
```

There are 2 problems:

1. I have to check with the `if let`... statement (but I know I don't need it)
2. I need an `else panic`, because without it `top_path` could be uninitialized (-> error).

Is it my mistake or is it Rust?

Answer (score 7):

the irc helped me with the following answer:

```
while let Some(top) = self.stack.pop() {
    let top_path = top.to_vec();
    let mut is_terminal = self.tree.root.is_terminal( top.to_vec() );

    self.apply_grammar(top_path);
}
```

and this looks *much* nicer.

Comment: Note: in case you do not know, this is called *Irrefutable Pattern*.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`Option::unwrap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) method, which panics on `None` just like your `if let ... else` expression:

```
while !self.stack.is_empty() {
    let top = self.stack.last().unwrap();
    let top_path = top.to_vec();
    self.stack.pop();
    self.apply_grammar(top_path);
}
```

but in this case it would be even clearer to use a `while let` block as you mentioned in your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should use an iterator. It's just as efficient (maybe more so), and is shorter:

```
fn main() {
    let stack = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6];

    // Consume the stack, pop from the beginning
    for i in stack {
        println!("{}", i);
    }

    let stack = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6];

    // Consume the stack, pop from the end
    for i in stack.into_iter().rev() {
        println!("{}", i);
    }

    let stack = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6];

    // Don't consume the stack, read from the beginning
    for i in &stack {
        println!("{}", i);
    }

    // Don't consume the stack, read from the end
    for i in stack.iter().rev() {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

In your example, Rust doesn't know there is any connection between `is_empty` and `pop`, so it has to handle the failure case in `pop`. An iterator exposes a more knowledgable interface to the vector, and can avoid checking for out-of-bounds to boot.

Comment: This won't work if you need to call methods that take `self` or `stack` by mutable reference inside the loop, however.

Comment: @mbrubeck sure, but then you aren't popping off the stack, and thus the  example in the question would be different ^_^.

Comment: In the example from the question, if `self.apply_grammar` takes `&mut self`, then the `while` or `while let` loops will work but a `for` loop will not.  [Simplified example](http://is.gd/rp1Jdx).  (You could work around this with `std::mem::replace`.)